# Indian National lost passport in Malaysia

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, security, malaysia

I'm from India had come to Malaysia in visiting visa near my friend to meet in between in emergency he went to India and I stay in Lodge for 6 days and I lost my passport and in 2 days my visiting visa will expire 30days and I had not complained yet to police station in fear. How can I get back to my hometown in India?

Comment: Try to reach the Indian Embassy in Malaysia.

Comment: If you lose your passport: Always contact police first, file a report, get a copy of the report, and then take it to your embassy/high commission.

Answer (score 3):

You need to go to the Indian High Comission, in Kuala Lumpa.

They can issue you with an emregency certificate, which will enable you to get back to India. You will need to have reported this to the police, filled in two forms, and travel to the Embassy between 09:30 and 12:00 Monday to Friday, and be ready to pay an RM76 fee. [You can read about it on this page of the embassy site.](http://indianhighcommission.com.my/passport.html)

The embassy also operates an emergency phone number for Indian citizens visiting Malaysia at **00-60122031745**. This may be useful if you can't readily get to Kuala Lumpa.