# Lost my passport in Malaysia and overstayed as a result. What should I do now?

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, malaysia, lost-documents

I applied for a police report and submitted it to the Indian High Commission whos said "Come on Tuesday" but I've overstayed now for three days and in three days have a flight to catch.

Should I go to Malaysian Immigration to pay the penalty for my overstay, or should I go to airport directly and pay the penalty?

Which is better and safer for me because I don't have enough money to travel from Kuala Lumpur to Putrajaya, so what can I do?

Comment: KL to putrajaya should just be about 4 ringgit via the train one way. If you can't afford that, you definitely can't afford the overstay penalty.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you imagine that you are overstaying solely because you lost your passport?  Is there a rule that when you lose your passport you must leave as soon as possible? That makes no sense. Or did you delay your departure, possibly because of the loss of your passport, until after the end of your initial period of admission?

Comment: No I don't have money and my ATM is not working here so

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Indian National lost passport in Malaysia](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67395/indian-national-lost-passport-in-malaysia)

Comment: @KH.Lee This question is cleary asking about something different - namely what to do when the lost passport causes an overstay. I suspect the answer is that the authorities should have been told as soon as an overstay was inevitable. What to do now however...

Comment: @CMaster, my first thought is that Rahul posted two question on the same story: "passport lost, (possible) overstay, what to do next?". But I agree that the first question _maybe_ posted _before_ overstay and this one is _after_, so it is possible that they could end up with two different answers...

Answer (score 8):

As described by a friend who went through this:

Since you lost the passport, you need to go to immigration department and [apply for a special pass](http://www.imi.gov.my/index.php/en/main-services/enforcement/loss-of-passport-travel-document.html). The link lists the documents you need to bring:

- Passport number / copy of the lost passport / travel document;
- New Passport / Travel Document;
- Police report;
- Plane / bus / ferry ticket (depart within 7 days)
- Money (see below)

those are not mandatory but would be helpful:

- Any evidence of entry (land passes/tickets/list of passengers);
- Certificate from the Embassy;
- Copy of pass / previous document (if any);

You will only get the pass if your overstay is 14 days or less. Come early and expect to spend a few hours there, there's a line.

Money: it will cost you 100 ringgit for the pass. Since you overstayed, you'll have to pay additional 30 ringgit for each day (in 2015) you would overstay until you leave the country, so if you are already late for 4 days and your flight leaves in 2 days, you'd have to pay for 6 days. So in your case its 280 ringgit. **Bring more money in case they raised the fine, or start collecting additional fees.**

You will get an "overstay" stamp in your passport, and will be banned from reentering Malaysia for some small period (2 or 3 days per each day overstayed).

This will only work if your overstay is less than 15 days.

Answer (score 3):

You are stranded without your passport, from the sound of your comments without money too and with an expired visa. This doesn't sound like something that can be answered generically, other than the advice to ask your embassy for help.

Comment: I want to know where shall I get the overstay stamp for 6 days and which way is better